# Parsing Huge CSV and Loading into MySQL DB

Tags: c#, mysql, csv

I have a program written in C# which reads a CSV, parses the data, makes a few transformations of the data before putting the newly conditioned data into a MySQL Database (handled in the class "anTix").  Code is below:

```
        int                    counter = 0;
        string                 lineStr;
        string[]               splitStr;
        anTix                  active = new anTick();
        System.IO.StreamReader file;

        file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
        while ( ( lineStr = file.ReadLine() ) != null )
        {
            counter++;
            splitStr = lineStr.Split( ',' );
            active.procData( splitStr[0], 
                             splitStr[1] + splitStr[2],
                             Convert.ToSingle( splitStr[3] ), 
                             Convert.ToInt16( splitStr[4] ), 
                             Convert.ToChar( splitStr[5] ) );
        }
        file.Close();
```

It's nothing fancy, but it gets the job done, even with what I had previously perceived as large files (1.5GB is the largest I've handled).  I've now graduated to larger datafile sizes (25-50GB), and I don't have the memory to deal with files that large.

After poking around a bit, I've done looked into memory mapped files, but I have some concerns about efficiency of the process (I've only used memory mapped files when dealing with concurrent processes in a file, never as a workaround for memory allocation) and I don't want to slow down the process for my typical 100-200MB files.

Are there any suggestions for an easier way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: Does the transformation depend on all the data in each given file? If so, can you describe them a little more?

Comment: No, the file is just a collection of lines to be parsed and put in a database, a holistic view of the file isn't required.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. `StreamReader.ReadLine()` only loads a single line at a time and uses no additional memory whether the file is 100 bytes or 100 GB. Is each line 100s of GB long? Use `StreamReader.Read()`. What does `active.procData` do? You aren't trying to same the stream in RAM are you? You shouldn't be doing that regardless the size if the file. I suspect the problem is not in the code you've shown us.

Comment: I agree with @DourHighArch - I created a 30 GB junk file and did something with every line using any additional memory. There's something else going on, something holding on to references that you don't intend. Memory profiler results?

Comment: Aha, I found the problem in the anTix class holding on to data when dealing with the database, not the file reading.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Splitting the file into smaller chunks and running [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) might help alleviate the issue. Keep a few seconds delay between runs. Disabling keys might also help. Also [see this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31752/mysql-load-data-infile-slows-by-80-after-a-few-gigs-of-input-with-innodb-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just split the file in a set of smaller files, and run your program on each of those smaller files? Or is there something that requires you to read the whole program at once?

Comment: It wouldn't be too much of an issue to split the file, but I'm unsure how to do that without the same headaches that I'm having now of "load giant file into memory".  Is there a quick way of splitting the file?

Comment: Try the unix 'split' command.  There is a flag to ensure that it doesn't split lines apart.

Comment: Just saw you are using C#.  Do you have cygwin? There is 'split' for that.